# How to throw error in user input?

Tags: java

I am trying to write a function, which will return an integer in range 1...9, based on input. But i cannot figure out how to control the correct result, so if user inputs a number outside of range 1 to 9 then it gives error.

Here is my code:

```
public static int pmove() throws IOException{
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  String br_rl = br.readLine();
  int br_int = Integer.parseInt(br_rl);
  if (br_int > 0 && br_int < 10) {
    return br_int;
  }
  else {
    // ???
  }
}
```

Comment: "it gives error." This very vague. What do you want the program to do?

Comment: throw new Exception("Throw from here"); try this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try something similar

```
public static int pmove() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String br_rl = br.readLine();
    int br_int = Integer.parseInt(br_rl);
    if (br_int > 0 && br_int < 10) {
        return br_int;
    } else {
        throw new IOException("Input Out of Range");
    }
}
```

You can create your own custom `Exception` to do this in better way.

Comment: Maybe `IllegalArgumentException` would be more appropriate.

Comment: @Tichodroma Or It is better to have custom Exception.

Comment: I figured that i can use try catch in main function to determine the required int, thanks for the answer however!

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `IOException` for input error of a *user*. *This* is the worst solution of all the possible ones. Either create your own exception (as one of the other answer recommends), or loop until the users enters valid input (as another answer recommends).

Comment: @HonzaZidek can't you see with your own eyes I had mention that in my answer?

Comment: @Ruchira: In your **code** you **do** throw `IOException` which is a complete misuse of this type of exception. Your answer should be "You *must* create your own custom `Exception`", not "you *can*". It's not enough to place a **wrong** code and just say "you may do it better" under it. It's against the quality standards of SO answers.

Comment: @Ruchira: Then your code is against the best practices. `IOException` is used for *technical* problems with I/O, not for invalid *user* input.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own user defined exception and you can use this.

Try this:-

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

//User define exception
class MyException extends Exception{
    public MyException(String error) {
        System.out.println("Error ::"+error);
    }
}

public class NumerTest {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String br_rl = br.readLine();
        int br_int = Integer.parseInt(br_rl);
        if (br_int > 0 && br_int < 10) {
        System.out.println("Your Number is ::"+br_int);
        }
        else {
            try{
                //Throw your own defined exception
                throw new MyException("Invalid Number Entry:::Try Again between 0-9");
            }catch(Exception e){}
        }

    }

}
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the to keep asking for input when the input is wrong then you can do this:

```
public static int pmove() throws IOException{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String br_rl = br.readLine();
    int br_int = Integer.parseInt(br_rl);
    while (br_int <= 0 || br_int >= 10) {
         System.out.println("Wrong input");
         br_rl = br.readLine();
         br_int = Integer.parseInt(br_rl);
    }
    return br_int;
}
```

Testing with `(System.out.println(pmove());` :

```
11
Wrong input
25
Wrong input
4
4
```

Now if you want to stop reading you can throw an exception like others have pointed.